# Does the reduced aerodynamic damping at higher altitudes affect the Vno (maneuvering speed) of an airplane?

Tags: aerodynamics, airspeed, flight-dynamics, g-forces

Since reduced aerodynamic damping at higher altitudes reduces the needed control input for maneuvers, is this just about the required force to move the controls or also about the speed of the resulting motion of the aircraft? If the latter, would full deflection of the controls at high altitude result in higher g-forces on the airplane for the same indicated airspeed, and because of this a lower Vno? Or is the effect of full deflection of the controls on the airplane actually the same at high altitude as it is at low altitude, regardless of aerodynamic damping?

Comment: Interesting.  TAS will be higher for a given IAS at altitude. Turn radii will be greater.  G force loads and control deflections will be similar (up to critical Mach values).  Less damping (thinner air) may lead one to err on the side of caution *changing* control settings due to potential overshoot *while changing*, but the Vno *indicated* may be similar, but limited to a Mach (TAS) value.  (Airliner pilots please chime in).